# "I (had) hated her for long before we split" — Simple Past or Past Perfect?

Tags: tenses, past-perfect, simple-past

I'm not certain whether using 'had hated' here is totally correct or not.

And if it is not, please explain why.

Answer (score 2):

The normal past tense, to describe a past event, would be simply

> "I hated her for [a] long [time] before we split."

The past perfect tense is used when referring to a completed action which occurred **prior** to another past event being referenced, as in:

> "I had hated her for a long time before the split, but grew fond again once we were no longer living under the same roof."

Notice how the use of the past perfect tense is used to denote the *completion* or *ending* of the action prior to another past event.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. Past perfect (“I had hated”) indicates that an action (“hate”) occurred *before* another action, also in the past (“split”). In particular, it is often used with verbs of state, such as *have*, *be*, *love*, and *hate*.

Whenever you *don’t* have an explicit indication of the relationship between two events—such as *before* or *then*—you must use past perfect. When the relationship is obvious, simple past is *also* correct (“I hated”).

If you are a Chinese speaker:

> past perfect 了 past (e.g., 昨天)
>
> past 了 present (e.g., 今天)